# Launching app in another device gives Multiple dex files define error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio to develop my app. The app works my Android 5.1 device, but when trying to install on another device (Android 4.2.2), I'm getting multiple dex files error.

Any ideas why that's happening? Is there a version dependency that might be tripping me up?

**Main gradle file:**

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' }
```

**App gradle:**

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prasoon.mg"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    //used in main activity
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //end
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'

    }
```

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` after `testInstrumentationRunner` https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: after addition of mutlidexenabled, app works fine android device 5.1 but Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException:

Comment: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: thanks, new error while run, Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzv$zza$zza.class

Comment: all library which includes support library exclude all. and add in android tag 'dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries false
    }'

Comment: able to resolved it by putting multiDexEnabled true and commented compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'. Thanks to everyone.